# problem with using annotations in acceleo

Tags: java, annotations, acceleo

Im very new to **acceleo**, for text generation(for java language) i'm using **ecore** file and **.mtl module.**

in my application there is a need of **annotations**, so I declared annotations in my ecore model. but the problem is i'm unable to check if condition with my annotation details( key,value) in MTL file.

my condition in **.mtl file** is

[if(r.getEAnnotation('sourcename').details.key.equalsIgnoreCase('keyname'))]
       [/if]

but here condition expression is not accepting in if block and even not accepting in let block also.

i'm able to print the values of my annotation source details(key,value) and even i'm able to print true or flase value of condition.

if any one know solution of this problem please replay me

Comment: What do you mean by "condition expression is not accepting in if block and even not accepting in let block also." ? Is there a compilation error on that line when you try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression `r.getEAnnotation('sourcename').details` returns a collection so the condition of your "if" is a collection of boolean, not a boolean. You could change it to something like:

```
[if(r.getEAnnotation('sourcename').details->first().key.equalsIgnoreCase('keyname'))] [/if]
```

or

```
[if(r.getEAnnotation('sourcename').details->collect(key.equalsIgnoreCase('keyname'))->size() > 0)] 

[/if]
```